# Matlab unique alternative

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to flag up instances of duplicated numbers in a short vector in Matlab. For example, in the case of:

A = [ 1 2 3 1 5 6 7 8 ]
B = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ]

A would flag true due to the double 1's, while B wouldn't.

Comparing vector with unique(vector) seems the obvious answer, and it's ok for a few cases, but the unique function proves to be pretty slow when you're using it 100000 times!

Any thoughts on a faster test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following test. This will output `1` if there are duplicate numbers, otherwise `0`.

```
(sum(diff(sort(A))==0))~=0
```

The `diff` function subtracts the number at position `n` from `n+1`. If you could actually write a function which does the same thing but just returns a `1` when it finds first instance of zero, i.e. duplicate numbers adjacent to each other. Probably you would have to write a MEX function to make it faster. The disadvantage of `diff()` function is that, it will scan the entire vector even if it is full of duplicate numbers.

I like the variant of the solution written in the comment below by @A. Klomp:

```
any(diff(sort(A))==0)
```

Comment: `any(diff(sort(a))==0)`

Comment: Has to be pretty fast! +1

Comment: I like it too! @A.Klomp !Good job! :)

Comment: WOW!!! This is much faster than the technique I was using with unique. Thanks everyone, especially @A.Klomp

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives. Not sure if they are faster than other answers:

```
sum(sum(bsxfun(@eq, A, A.'))) > numel(A)
nnz(triu(bsxfun(@eq, A, A.'), 1))
any(sum(pdist(A(:))==0))
any(accumarray(A(:), 1) > 1)
nnz(sparse(A(:), 1, 1) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways to do this.

1) you could sort the list first and then check if you get any duplicate numbers right after each other i.e `[1,1,2,3,4 ..]` this is a `O(nlog(n))` algorithm because you got to sort the list (hopefully using merge sort or quick sort which should be built in) and the run through it.

```
sort(list)
for( i =1:len(list))
   if(i < len(list) -1 && list[i] == list[i+1]) return false;
end
```

2) You could just do a `O(n^2)` algorithm where you just brute force cross check each element with another in the list. Basically comparing it self to a unique list but instead of having another list you compare it to itself.

For Example:

```
 for(i= 1:len(list))
    for(j = 1:len(list))
      if(list[i] == list[j]) return false;
    end
 end
```